# Dojo EnhancedGrid CoulmnSelector checkbox styling

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

My Javascript code for creating dojo enhanced datagrid is:

```
grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
                            store: store,
                            rowSelector: 'auto',
                            **plugins: {indirectSelection: {headerSelector:true, width:'auto', styles:"text-align: center;"}},**
                            structure: [
                                          {field: 'msname', width: 'auto', name: 'Milestone'},
                                          {field: 'description', width: 'auto', name: 'Description'},
                                          {field: 'msorder', width: 'auto', name: 'Milestone Order'},
                                          {field: 'eventtype', width: 'auto', name: 'Event Type'},
                                          {field: 'isngrp', width: 'auto', name: 'Is NGRP?'},
                                          {field: 'eventAttribute', width: 'auto', name: 'Event Attribute(s)'}
                                      ]
                        },"grid");
                        grid.startup();
```

But the styling of checkbox is not proper. There is a small square inside the checkbox. Any idea how to resolve it. The screenshot is:

[image: Enhanced Grid checkbox styling]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had missed enhancedgrid.css to be included in the body of my page. It renders fine now.